# Laravel 5.5 y Request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Buenos días, intentaré explicarme lo mejor posible, soy nuevo en Laravel

Lo que deseo hacer es poder guardar campos de la DB con datos pero que no están en el formulario, porque esos datos los traigo desde un webservice, el cual funciona bien, lo comprobe.

Entiendo que el Request se ejecuta antes que el STORE, y supongo que allí está el problema. Tanto si saco estos campos del Request como si los dejo igual me tira el error. La única forma que encontre de hacerlo es guardando 1 por 1 los campos einclusive los que si están en el formulario.

Por ejemplo

```
public function store(DRequest $dRequest, D $d)
{
    try {
        $respuesta = $this->search($dRequest->input('nro_afiliado'), $dRequest->input('fecha'));
        $dRequest->apellido_nombre = $respuesta['apellido_nombre'];
        $dRequest->sexo = $respuesta['sexo'];
        $dRequest->edad = $respuesta['edad'];
        $dRequest->fecha_nacimiento = Carbon::parse($respuesta['fecha_nacimiento'])->format('Y-m-d');

        $dRequest->nro_afiliado = $respuesta['numero_afi'];
        $dRequest->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    } catch (\SoapFault $e) {
        echo "ERROR EN EL SOAP";
        echo "<br />";
        echo $e->faultcode;
        echo "<br />";
        echo $e->faultstring;
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Error Exception luego del Webservice";
    }

    $d = new D;
    $d = $this->fillD($dRequest, $d);
    $d->save();

    Session::flash('message-success', 'Archivo guardado satisfactoriamente.');
    return redirect()->route('d.index');
}
```

En este caso $respuesta tiene los valores del webservice y se los asigno al request, pero esto no funciona si no hago lo siguiente

```
 private function fillD(DRequest $dRequest, D $d)
{
    $d->user_id = $dequest->user_id;
    $d->firma_localidad_id = $dRequest->firma_localidad_id;
    $d->apellido_nombre = $dRequest->apellido_nombre;
    $d->fecha_nacimiento = $dRequest->fecha_nacimiento;
    $d->edad = $dRequest->edad;
    $d->sexo = $dRequest->sexo;
    $d->anio = $dRequest->anio;
    $d->puntaje_fim = $dRequest->puntaje_fim;
    $d->firma_profesional = $dRequest->firma_profesional;
    $d->firma_fecha = $dRequest->firma_fecha;


    return $d;
}
```

El Webservice tiene solamente los campos apellido_nombre y sexo el resto son de la tabla.

La pregunta es como puede asignarle al Request valores a campos que no están en el formulario y que los obtengo a través de un webservice, sin que me tire el error, de esa forma puedo guardarlo asi

```
Noticia::create($noticiaRequest->all());
```

Y en una linea de codigo resuelvo el tema de guardar

GRACIAS de antemano y perdón si no me pude explicar bien

Comment: Prueba con Request $request . O no es lo que querés?

Comment: Esta puesto el Request el tema que al no estar esos campos en el formulario y si en el Request me tira error. porque segun tengo entendido antes de ir al STORE va al Request y esos campos estan vacios entonces me tira error. Y si los saco del request no puedo asignarselos

Comment: Si es tan vacíos tendría que largar null. Usaste la facada?

Answer (score 0):

la respuesta es que primero debes construir un array que contenga todos los datos; si una parte de los datos los aporta el array A y otra parte el array B.

Lo que necesitamos es hacer un merge:

```
public function store(Request $request, D $d){
...
/* aca use ->except para excluir el token csrf, si no usas token csrf puedes usar ->all */
$request_final = array_merge($request->except(['_token']), $array_de_webservice);
/* esto producira un array de todos los campos de array A + array B */
/* finalmente creamos */
Noticia::create($request_final);
```

Saludos espero te sea útil

Comment: Pregunto no es lo mismo asiganarle al request los valores de a uno?? Obviamente esos campos tienen que estar en el request verdad?

Comment: por ejemplo asi?

Comment: $dRequest->sexo = $respuesta['sexo'];
$dRequest->edad = $respuesta['edad'];

Comment: Esos campos sexo y edad estan en el modelo, estan en la tabla, estan en el request pero no estan en el formulario..

Comment: Tambien puedes usar $request->merge, te adjunto un enlace [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-modify-request-data-before-saving)

Comment: Creo que lo solucione con el link que me enviaste, muchisimas gracias era eso creo

Answer (score 0):

No puedes asignar al objeto Request de Laravel nuevos valores de esa manera, para modificar el objeto Request debes de hacer un merge

```php
public function store(Request $request, D $d)
{
    //$request->merge(['field' => $value]);
    //En tu caso
    $request->merge($respuesta);
    Noticia::create($request->all()); //Te recomiendo que solamente pongas como fill los campos que necesites en el modelo
}
```